# How can I add axis scale in R?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have some problem with curve3d.
I have a following equation to be plotted:

```
library(emdbook)
curve3d ( 87.56 + 0.772*x - 0.022*x*y + 0.162*x^2, xlim=c(0,70), ylim=c(0,70), xlab="axe1", ylab="axe2", zlab="axe3", col="green", phi = 10, theta = 180)
```

How i can add scale to axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By scale you mean ticks, I guess?

`emdbook::curve3d()` uses `graphics::persp()` as a default to plot. To add ticks you can change the `persp()` parameter `ticktype` from `"simple"` to `"detailed"`. See `?persp` for even more options.

```
library(emdbook)
curve3d ( 
  87.56 + 0.772*x - 0.022*x*y + 0.162*x^2, 
  xlim=c(0,70), ylim=c(0,70), 
  xlab="axe1", ylab="axe2", zlab="axe3", 
  col="green", 
  phi = 10, theta = 180,
  sys3d = "persp",
  ticktype = "detailed"
)
```

[image]

By the way I would consider using `sys3d = "rgl"` to get a real, movable 3D plot. `rgl` is a powerful 3D plotting package.

Comment: Thank you, Nevrome. Yes i meant it.